# How can i add an outlet to an existing combination light switch?

Tags: electrical

I have an old existing double light switch fixture that id like to add an outlet to. Can i do this? Ive been looking online and haven't seen much for info. Here are the pics of the current light switch[[image: side image][image: inside][image: side image]

Comment: Do those 2 switches control separate things?  Or is one of them inoperative now?

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. You have your always hot white wire, that should be marked with black tape, energizing the switch. You then have the two load wires, black and red, coming off the switch to control two devices. You are missing the neutral that would be required to add the outlet.

If you can combined the two devices at the fixture and connect them to the red wire, connect the hot to the black and the white to the neutral all at the fixtures, then replace the combination switch with a single switch. Connect the black, hot, to switch and pigtail to outlet. Connect red to switch and connect white , neutal, to outlet... just a thought.

Comment: This is in the bathroom. Theres a ceiling light and a vanity light. Originally there was an ugly medicine cabinet with light and outlet on it, but this has been removed and replaced with vanity light fixture so theres currently no outlets :(  I thought i could just wire an outlet off of the switch but this sounds more complicated than i can do myself.

Comment: @AliKohn It's not more complicated than you can do yourself, it's more impossible than you can do yourself :)

Comment: @AliKohn more like "the wires just aren't in the right places, sadly, so even an electrician would be stuck doing it the expensive, messy way"